# Calling JNI with Android NDK issue

Tags: android, image-processing, camera, android-ndk

I have a C function that I'm calling from Java using the Android NDK. Essentially it takes the camera data and converts it from YUV to RGB format. The problem is I'm not sure what object type imageOut is returned in as in C it's simply of type jobject. This is the snippet of code I have (unfortunately I have nothing else to go by):

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_twothreetwo_zoomplus_ZoomPlus_yuvrgb(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jbyteArray imageIn, jint widthIn, jint heightIn, jobject imageOut, jint widthOut, jint heightOut)
{
    LOGI("width is %d; height is %d;",widthIn,heightIn);

    jbyte *cImageIn = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, imageIn, NULL);
    jbyte *cImageOut = (jbyte*)(*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, imageOut);


    unsigned int *rgbs = (unsigned int*)cImageOut;

    int half_widthIn = widthIn >> 1;

      //the end of the luminance data
      int lumEnd = (widthIn * heightIn) >> 1;
      //points to the next luminance value pair
      int lumPtr = 0;
      //points to the next chromiance value pair
      int chrPtr = lumEnd;
      //the end of the current luminance scanline
      int lineEnd = half_widthIn;
      unsigned short *yuvs;
      int x,y;
      for (y=0;y<heightIn;y++) {
        int yPosOut=(y*widthOut) >> 1;
        for (x=0;x<half_widthIn;x++) {
          //read the luminance and chromiance values
          int Y1 = yuvs[lumPtr++];
          int Y2 = (Y1 >> 8) & 0xff;
          Y1 = Y1 & 0xff;
          int Cr = yuvs[chrPtr++];
          int Cb = ((Cr >> 8) & 0xff) - 128;
          Cr = (Cr & 0xff) - 128;

          int R, G, B;
          //generate first RGB components
          B = Y1 + ((454 * Cb) >> 8);
          if (B < 0) B = 0; if (B > 255) B = 255;
          G = Y1 - ((88 * Cb + 183 * Cr) >> 8);
          if (G < 0) G = 0; if (G > 255) G = 255;
          R = Y1 + ((359 * Cr) >> 8);
          if (R < 0) R = 0; if (R > 255) R = 255;
          int val = ((R & 0xf8) << 8) | ((G & 0xfc) << 3) | (B >> 3);

          //generate second RGB components
          B = Y1 + ((454 * Cb) >> 8);
          if (B < 0) B = 0; if (B > 255) B = 255;
          G = Y1 - ((88 * Cb + 183 * Cr) >> 8);
          if (G < 0) G = 0; if (G > 255) G = 255;
          R = Y1 + ((359 * Cr) >> 8);
          if (R < 0) R = 0; if (R > 255) R = 255;
          rgbs[yPosOut+x] = val | ((((R & 0xf8) << 8) | ((G & 0xfc) << 3) | (B >> 3)) << 16);
        }
        //skip back to the start of the chromiance values when necessary
        chrPtr = lumEnd + ((lumPtr  >> 1) / half_widthIn) * half_widthIn;
        lineEnd += half_widthIn;
      }


    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, imageIn, cImageIn, JNI_ABORT);
}
```

I'm calling the function in the onPreviewFrame function:

```
public native void yuvrgb(byte[] yuvImageIn, int widthIn, int heightIn, Bitmap imageOut, int widthOut, int heightOut);

    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
    {
      yuvrgb(data,480,640,bitmapWip,480,640);
      cameraImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapWip);
    }
```

As you can see, I'm currently declaring imageOut as a Bitmap which is where I think I'm going wrong as I just guessed the type.

I don't get any errors, the app simply crashes instantly. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This example was originally done to map image data on a texture in openGL and IMHO imageOut should be ByteBuffer (because GetDirectBufferAddress is used to load data from Buffer). But I recently tried to use this too and didn't manage to get it work.

Comment: Yeah, just tried to cast it to a ByteBuffer but it still crashes. I don't suppose you found another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

cImageOut is an array of bytes. It's declared at the top of your C function:

`jbyte *cImageOut = (jbyte*)(*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, imageOut);`

You should declare it as a byte array in your java code and then convert it to a Bitmap using `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray`

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: Hi ethan, I've tried casting it as a byte array but the app still crashed as soon as it opens. Perhaps I'm doing something else wrong? This is what I'm doing:

private byte[] bitmapWip;